# ElasticSearch's MasterService taking too long to compute cluster state and throw ProcessClusterEventTimeoutException

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an application that adds thousands of documents per second to our ES cluster. Each time we roll over the indices to which we are writing, and we start writing to new indices, we get the following errors, which don't allow ingesting documents for about 1 minute. After that 1 minute, everything goes back to normal until we rollover the index again.

```
[WARN ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [NODE_NAME_1] took [28.3s], which is over [10s], to compute cluster state update for [put-mapping[_doc, _doc, ...
[DEBUG][o.e.a.a.i.m.p.TransportPutMappingAction] [NODE_NAME_1] failed to put mappings on indices [[[INDEX_1/SOME_ID]]], type [_doc]
org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.ProcessClusterEventTimeoutException: failed to process cluster event (put-mapping) within 30s
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$Batcher.lambda$onTimeout$0(MasterService.java:143) [elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507) [?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.MasterService$Batcher.lambda$onTimeout$1(MasterService.java:142) [elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:703) [elasticsearch-7.5.2.jar:7.5.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) [?:?]
```

In the first line, I put ellipsis at the end as it's actually quite large, here an image of what we're seeing (the line ends abruptly as you see in the image):

[image]

Do you know what those error messages are about?

Is it possible we are seeing those messages because of our cluster state being too large? Would that mean we have too many shards or nodes?

Thanks.

**Note:**

- We use ElasticSearch 7.5.2
- We don't use ILM, when I say "roll over our indices" what we do is to start writing to new indices that we created hours ago but were not using. Then we stop writing to the old indices.

Comment: how many shards you have ?

Comment: We have around 30.000 shards

Comment: @MondKin, 30k shards on 1 ES node, or in cluster and what is the heap size of your data node? and how many nodes in your cluster?

Comment: We have 60 data nodes in total, in a hot-warm architecture, some of the nodes have 32GiB heaps and others have 16GiB.

Comment: @MondKin, btw great core ES internals questions, liked it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error comes when ES is not able to cope up with the large cluster state, and the default timeout to update cluster state is 10s, but as mentioned in your error message, it took ~30 seconds.

**Cluster state is computed on the master node and then publish a Diff(node was present) or entire cluster state(if a new node joins a cluster) by `MasterService.java` class of Elasticsearch.**

you have huge no of shards information, which is maintained in the cluster state, your master node is not able to compute state within default `10s`.

Below is the code from Elasticsearch class `org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService`, which tries to update the cluster state and throws this exception.

```
try {
    UpdateTask updateTask = new UpdateTask(config.priority(), source, new SafeClusterApplyListener(listener, logger), executor);
    if (config.timeout() != null) {
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(updateTask, config.timeout(),
            () -> threadPool.generic().execute(
                () -> listener.onFailure(source, new ProcessClusterEventTimeoutException(config.timeout(), source))));
    } else {
        threadPoolExecutor.execute(updateTask);
    }
}
```

And you can check the exception class `org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.ProcessClusterEventTimeoutException` code as below

```
public ProcessClusterEventTimeoutException(TimeValue timeValue, String source) {
        super("failed to process cluster event (" + source + ") within " + timeValue);
    }
```

You can look at the above code, which will help you to better understand the problem.

Some suggestions to fix the issues:

1. **Increase the heap size and CPU of master node**, so that the cluster state can be computed quickly as in your case, even the first step of calculating takes 30 sec. which means your master nodes doesn't have enough infrastructure to compute it fast.
2. Delete unnecessary indices, which would reduce the no of shards and cluster state.
3. Below are settings for publishing the cluster state, this is the second step, if you see publishing taking a long time, then you can do it if you are OK your some if data nodes become unavailable for this duration.

> ```
> cluster.publish.info_timeout = 10s default(maybe this can work)
> cluster.publish.timeout = 30s by default
> ```

Comment: Indeed, we have a way of reducing the number of shards, we'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: @MondKin i wouldnt suggest more than 1500 shards per node ( best to keep it below 1000)

Comment: @MondKin, Added another important link in my answer, which would help to configure optimal number of shards in your cluster.

Comment: @MondKin any luck?

Comment: Tomorrow I'll be able to tell, because of some dynamics on our system.

Comment: @MondKin, sure looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Thanks all for your help! We increased the heap in masters from 8GB to 16GB and this seems to have improved the situation a lot. We still see some messages telling us the it took too long to compute cluster state, but they are fewer than before. We have not yet increased the heap in the data nodes that were 16GB to 32GB. We also reduced shard numbers, but due to the dynamics of our system, this is a slow process. We've only reduced like 100 shards out of the 30k, so whether that is helping the system is hard to tell at this point.

Comment: @MondKin its nice to hear the feedback, yeah this kind of issue would not go away with just one improvement and sometimes requires serirs of recovery to get the desirable state, but I am glad that you are heading into the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Thanks!

Comment: @MondKin, So I just spent some more time on this and found some useful information, which can quickly solve your issue, which is increasing the size of your master node, as in your exception, calculation(first steps) takes more time. pls have a look and ping me if you have any doubt