# Elasticsearch election loop

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch cluster with ~40 nodes of which 30 are master eligible. The cluster holds ~30k shards in two different availability zones. All nodes are in one location with a low latency local network and all master nodes operate on SSDs.

When the current master node disconnects from the cluster (e.g. by stopping it) the system goes into an infinite loop of cluster join requests between the other nodes which always fail due to `org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.CoordinationStateRejectedException: incoming term 418727 does not match current term 418729`.
This happens already a few milli seconds after the original master node disconnected.

Whenever this happens we have to shut down a lot of nodes manually before this resolves. Causing a long downtime of the cluster due to the manual intervention and recovery taking some time.

Is there any setting we need to configure for large clusters to be able to handle their master node disconnecting?

Comment: First of all, you should reduce the master eligible nodes from 30 to 3, as you are shutting down the nodes, why you are not changing the role of them when you are restarting them?

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't make sense to have that many master-eligible nodes, it creates a lot of unnecessary chatter

Comment: Should the other notes then be voting nodes or just plain data nodes with no involvement into the election process at all?

Comment: @Dero, they should be just plain data and co-ordinating nodes, but not master eligible ones

Comment: @Dero [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519228/4039431) answer might help you.

Comment: If it were timeouts that we experience I would've understood it, but as said in the original post this happens to us milliseconds after the master left the cluster. Anyway reducing master nodes now and see where it will get us.

Comment: @Dero, yeah thats anyway needed, let me know how it goes

Comment: Took some time until we got back to a case where we needed to restart master nodes, but so far it looks good with a reduced number of masters. A handful of master changes yesterday went through without issues. Thanks for the tip!